# Tensorflow Serving: GetModelMetaData and automatic configuration of tf.example input nodes

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am writing a TensorFlow Serving client in C++ that sits inside a database server and makes TensorFlow models available as database procedures. The whole machinery autoconfigures the data types and necessary conversions between database tables and inputa and output tensors based on the responses it retrieves from TensorFlow Serving modelservers via the GetModelMetaData request/response mechanism.

So far I have used "raw" input tensors to talk to various models (Inception_v3, various regression models). By "raw" I mean that the values for the input tensors are the plain datatypes requested by the model in contrast to values wrapped as tf.example records.

For illustration, looking at the "half_plus_two" model from the TensorFlow Serving examples section. It expects an "x" float input and returns a "y" float output. It features both a "raw" input mode in the "serving_default" signature, as well as a "wrapped" one in the "classify_x_to_y" signature:  (Excerpt from the GetModelMetaData response):

```
Model Metadata: 
model_spec {
  name: "multisig"
  version {
    value: 1
  }
}
metadata {
  key: "signature_def"
  value {
    [type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.serving.SignatureDefMap] {
      signature_def {
        key: "classify_x_to_y"
        value {
          inputs {
            key: "inputs"
            value {
              name: "tf_example:0"
              dtype: DT_STRING
              tensor_shape {
                unknown_rank: true
              }
            }
          }
          outputs {
            key: "scores"
            value {
              name: "y:0"
              dtype: DT_FLOAT
              tensor_shape {
                dim {
                  size: -1
                }
                dim {
                  size: 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
          method_name: "tensorflow/serving/classify"
        }
      }
      signature_def {
        key: "serving_default"
        value {
          inputs {
            key: "x"
            value {
              name: "x:0"
              dtype: DT_FLOAT
              tensor_shape {
                dim {
                  size: -1
                }
                dim {
                  size: 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
          outputs {
            key: "y"
            value {
              name: "y:0"
              dtype: DT_FLOAT
              tensor_shape {
                dim {
                  size: -1
                }
                dim {
                  size: 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
          method_name: "tensorflow/serving/predict"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While I can automatically deduce what tensor to create for the explicitly specified "raw" tensor (i.e. a vector of floats), I have no good way to figure out what to put into the serialized tf.example record that the "classify_x_to_y" signature wants (reading the textual description I know of course that it wants a tf.example with a float value under the key 'x', the question is, how is one supposed to automatically deduce that from the GetModelMetaDataResponse above ?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow serving supports different inference APIs, for example, Classify, Regress and Predict (https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service.proto). 
 - The "serving_default" signature is for the Predict API (with method name "tensorflow/serving/predict"). The Predict API is tensor-oriented, so you can deduce what tensors to create.
- The "classify_x_to_y" signature is for the Classify API (with method name "tensorflow/serving/classify"). The Classify API uses tf.Example, and you need to know what features should be included in the tf.Example. If you have access to the model export (i.e., SavedModel), you may be able to deduce that information, but you won't be able to tell it just from the signature.
- Regress is similar to Classify.

Can you control your model to always export the predict signature and only use the Predict API for inference? Predict is a lower-level API than Classify and Regress, and it should support all the functionalities supported by Classify and Regress (and more).